# How to find combination of multiple cells in a range in excel

Tags: excel

How can I find all of multiple cell values of an excel workbook in a column of other workbook?

Example:I have 2 workbooks [workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dRlr.jpg) and [workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7s8.jpg)

in Workbook 1 I need a formula in D1 which finds all the words of the first row in workbook 2 range A:A and returns the value of second column of workbook 2. 
For instance, In D1 the formula needs to return 1423.00, though there is an extra word in A1 - "boy".

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far.  See [ask] as well as **how to create a [mcve]** and more about topics at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Will there be only one row in Workbook 2 for each name/year combination, i.e. "Arsen Gyulgyulyan 1989 boy" will only occur once?

Answer (score 0):

try this per the sample image,

```
=INDEX(G:G, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2, F$1:F$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2, F$1:F$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2, F$1:F$5))), 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample given

> workbook 1 name is Book17 and workbook 2 name is Book19 in below formula. Apply the below formula in Book17 in D2

```
=TEXT(IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2&" "&B2&" "&C2,[Book19]Sheet1!A2)),"Not Match",INDEX([Book19]Sheet1!A2:B2,1,2)),".00")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample given

> workbook 1 name is Book17 and workbook 2 name is Book19 in below formula. Apply the below formula in Book17 in D2

```
=TEXT(IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2&" "&B2&" "&C2,[Book19]Sheet1!A2)),"Not Match",INDEX([Book19]Sheet1!A2:B2,1,2)),".00")
```

workbook 1:

[image]

Workbook 2:

[image]